# Hide left navigation but not search refiners or managed metadata navigation settings

Tags: master-page, navigation, managed-metadata, managed

It appears that left hand navigation has been hidden on all our sites.  I'm assuming that it was by design and baked into the masterpage?  We really need to have access to search refiners and managed metadata navigation but currently everything is hidden.

I'm assumed this line of code is driving the left hand nav:  div class="ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin"

Any attempts I have made to modify have not worked (btw, I have no experience in this and unfortunately we have no one in our IT department that can assist).

I tried:  ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin { display: none } /* hide only quick links */ 
but this didn't work either..

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following css:

```
#sideNavBox{display:none !important;}
#contentBox{margin:0; width:100%;min-width: 100%;}
```

If that doesn't work, open your site collection in SharePoint Designer. Create a new page layout with 2 column layout. In the left column, there will be refiners and right would contain the search results. Associate the page layout to the search page.

The page layout would be like:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#sideNavBox{display:none;}
#contentBox{margin:0; width:100%;min-width: 100%;}
</style>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<div class="container">
<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spproxywebpartmanager"></WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 srchLeft">

        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="leftZone" runat="server" title="Refiners"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 srchRight">
            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="rightZone" runat="server" title="Search List"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</asp:Content>
```